# Racket - is it possible to define and use the same language in a single file?

Tags: macros, racket

I like to write code using org-mode and [ob-racket](https://github.com/togakangaroo/ob-racket). It works quite well for my purposes (mostly pragmatic scripting and solving code challenges as I slowly learn the patterns of this cool language). I am trying to understand language creation and a limitation is that ob-racket as is will only ever generate a single file for me, yet every example of creating a custom language I can find (largely just Beautiful Racket) uses separate files for the language definition and its usage.

I would assume - this being lisp after all - that it is possible to define a custom reader and/or a custom extender and then use them all in the same file. Can someone give me an example of how to do this or is it not doable?

Comment: I think technically the answer is no, but depending on your constraints you might be able to get close to the spirit of what you want by using at-exp to capture text and macros to read that text at expansion-time (as opposed to read-time)

Comment: ugh, if that's the case I suppose I could modify ob-racket to take a language-definition header arg that points to a named source block and generate both together...but that sounds like a bunch of elisp to learn. Learning lisp to make lisp in a lisp editor...sounds about right

Comment: I had intended expansion-time within racket, no elisp needed, but speaking of editor-support, syntax-highlighting would not be available in the "custom-language" in my vision of it

Comment: @AlexKnauth so how do languages like 2d mode work? I can write what seems to me like fairly regular racket and then do `#2dmatch` and start drawing rectangles...